How do I convert Kilobytes to Gigabytes in a Jolt Transform?
I want to add a conversion command from Kilobytes to Gigabytes in my Jolt Transform.
My Jolt Transform example
Input JSON :
[
  {
    "storage": [
      {
        "NAME": "sda",
        "TYPE": "disk",
        "FSTYPE": "",
        "SIZE": "214748364800",
        "MOUNTPOINT": "",
        "PKNAME": ""
      },
      {
        "NAME": "sda1",
        "TYPE": "part",
        "FSTYPE": "",
        "SIZE": "1048576",
        "MOUNTPOINT": "",
        "PKNAME": "sda"
      },
      {
        "NAME": "sda2",
        "TYPE": "part",
        "FSTYPE": "ext4",
        "SIZE": "2147483648",
        "MOUNTPOINT": "/boot",
        "PKNAME": "sda"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Jolt Transform:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "storage*": {
          "@(1,&)": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "storage": {
        "*": {
          "NAME": "storage.[&1].drive_name",
          "SIZE": "storage.[&1].capacity",
          "TYPE": "storage.[&1].type_enum"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Desired Output:
{
  "storage": [
    {
      "drive_name": "sda",
      "capacity": "200",
      "type_enum": "disk"
    },
    {
      "drive_name": "sda1",
      "capacity": "0.0009",
      "type_enum": "part"
    },
    {
      "drive_name": "sda2",
      "capacity": "2",
      "type_enum": "part"
    }
  ]
}

I would like to list Gigabytes in the CAPACITY output fields.
Kilobytes/(1024x1024x1024) = Gigabytes
I'm new to Jolt Transform and in search of good course material, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
Arjan

Sorry for that Barbaros. I've added the text...

You can add a modify spec along with a divideAndRound function such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "storage*": {
          "@(1,&)": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "storage": {
        "*": {
          "NAME": "storage.[&1].drive_name",
          "SIZE": "storage.[&1].capacity",
          "TYPE": "storage.[&1].type_enum"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "storage": {
        "*": {
          "capacity": "=divideAndRound(6,@(1,&),1073741824)"// this number is 1024*104*1024 
          // @(1,&) replicates the current attribute eg. "capacity" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Thanks a lot Barbaros!
Very impressive

No worries @Arjan don't neglect to voteup and accept the answer please, thanks in advance.
